# How to use findNavController() on itemOnClickListener of an adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation

Im having a problem on my navigation, first i have an A fragment which has a recycler view, when i use the navigation to move to another fragment (B fragment) and come back to my A fragment i cant seem to be able to click on the item contained in the recycler view, it raises me "View androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{1f8e1b2 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1823} does not have a NavController set". If i dont move in beetween fragments (stay in A fragment) it works just fine.

The onItemClicked on my adapter calls a findNavController().

ps: Sry for my bad english as im not native, and this is my first post

This is my MainActivity:
`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainMenuBinding
    private lateinit var bottomNav: BottomNavigationView
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    val authViewModel: AuthViewModel by viewModels()

    val TAG: String = "ReceitaListingFragment"


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        startUI()
    }

    private fun setNavController(){
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        setupWithNavController(bottomNav,navController)
    }

    private fun startUI() {

        binding = ActivityMainMenuBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
        setNavController()
        bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId){
                R.id.recipes -> {
                    val connected_to_internet:Boolean = isOnline(this)
                    val fragment:Fragment = RecipeListingFragment()
                    fragment.arguments = Bundle().apply {
                        putBoolean("connectivity",connected_to_internet)
                    }
                    replaceFragment(RecipeListingFragment())
                }
                R.id.profile -> replaceFragment(ProfileFragment())
            }
            true
        }

    }
    

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment : Fragment){

        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host,fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

`

this is my main_activity.xml:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/app_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E3E3E4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bordeux"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bordeux"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`

this is how i initialize my adapter in RecipeListingFragment:

`

```
private val adapter by lazy {
    RecipeListingAdapter(
        onItemClicked = {pos,item ->

            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_receitaListingFragment_to_receitaDetailFragment,Bundle().apply {

                putParcelable("note",item)
            })
        },
        this.authModel
    )
}
```

`

this is how i set my adapter in RecipeListingFragment:

`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
```

`

this is my navigation.xml:

`

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/receitaListingFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/receitaListingFragment"
        android:name="com.example.projectfoodmanager.ui.recipe.RecipeListingFragment"
        android:label="fragment_receita_listing"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recipe_listing" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_receitaListingFragment_to_receitaDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/receitaDetailFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_receitaListingFragment_to_profileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/receitaDetailFragment"
        android:name="com.example.projectfoodmanager.ui.recipe.RecipeDetailFragment"
        android:label="fragment_recipe_detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recipe_detail" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_receitaDetailFragment_to_receitaListingFragment"
            app:destination="@id/receitaListingFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.example.projectfoodmanager.ui.profile.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_receitaListingFragment"
            app:destination="@id/receitaListingFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/calenderFragment"
        android:name="com.example.projectfoodmanager.ui.views.CalenderFragment"
        android:label="fragment_calender"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_calender" >
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/favoritesFragment"
        android:name="com.example.projectfoodmanager.ui.views.FavoritesFragment"
        android:label="fragment_favorites"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorites" >
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/goalFragment"
        android:name="com.example.projectfoodmanager.ui.views.GoalFragment"
        android:label="fragment_goal"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_goal" >
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try to using RecyclerView and move fragment navigation to your Fragment.

Your Adapter:

```
class MyCustomAdapter(
     val openFragment: () -> Unit
) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<PromoAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
    
        holder.button.setOnClickListener {

        openFragment()
       
    }
}
```

}

In Fragment:

```
 val mAdapter = MyCustomAdapter(
     openFragment = { 
      // Navigate to Fragment 
 }
```

)